# Event should trigger when Toastr notification appears

Tags: protractor, toastr, angular-toastr

i want to trigger an event using protractor for close the Toastr notification messages. whenever the notification appears this event should triggered.. is this possible??

I have 10 forms ,i am validating these forms using protractor. In each form i have editable text fields. If you add/edit/delete any fields you will get toastr notification message. I want to close these messge whenever it appears in my appliaction.
is this possible?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `JS` code while running your test for closing `toastr` notification, you could try this one (I tested it in their demo project - run this code `toastr.remove()` in a console when toastr notification was shown):

```
await browser.executeScript(toastr.remove())
```

note that `browser.executeScript()` return `Promise` so you need to resolve it.